# laravel [Vue warn]: Error compiling a template

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am getting error while compiling Vue. I have included at the bottom of the page

```
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        @yield('script')
    </script>
```

From the blade I inserting a javascript

```
 @section('script')

 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 6000
});

  });
  @endsection
```

What is the right way to insert jquery inside a template

I have included the script in app.js

```
require('./jquery-ui');
require('./bootstrap');
require('./bootstrap-dropdownhover.min');
require('./custom');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert `script` tag inside Vue template, but you can insert `script` tag outside Vue scope.

You can use [Laravel Blade Stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#stacks)

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#stacks

```
@push('scripts')
    <script> put whatever you want here </script>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions above seem accurate, but a simple unclosed div might be your problem, I had the same issue, my mistake was that I had an unclosed div.

~regards